# comparing two files and extracting info from both using awk

Tags: bash, awk

cat file1:

```
a
b
c
d
e
```

cat file2:

```
a  10
c  20
e  30
f  40
```

The desired output file is:

```
a  10
b
c  20
d
e  30
f  40
```

I've tried using awk but I ended with all the lines of file1 repeated.
Many thanks

Comment: What's the logic that governs that output?

Comment: "I've tried using awk" .. you need to include code in your Q so we can help fix it! Else try searching on `[linux] join` or `[bash] join` and read `man join`. Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

Read in both files and hash them to an array (`a`). If you read in `file1` before `file2` the collisions will be in your favor. In awk:

```
$ awk '{a[$1]=$0} END{for(i in a) print a[i]}' file1 file2
a  10
b
c  20
d
e  30
f  40
```

Explained:

```
{
    a[$1]=$0        # hash all records to a 
} 
END {               # after processing both files
    for(i in a)     # iterate thru every key in a
        print a[i]  # and output their values
}
```

Due to the nature of `for(i in a)` the output order is random.

Answer (score 2):

another `awk` and less smart way to do this

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR {a[$1]=$2; next} 
       $1 in a {$2=a[$1]; delete a[$1]} 
               1; 
       END     {for(k in a) print k,a[k]}' file2 file1

a 10
b
c 20
d
e 30
f 40
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if `awk` is a hard requirement for the OP but here's an alternative solution using `join` which seems more appropriate for the job at hand (as @shellter also pointed out):

```
$ join -a1 -a2 file1 file2
```